# Update a Google Sheet Using HTTP Request in Postman

Tags: google-api, postman, google-sheets-api

I have a server needing to update a shared Google Sheet. It generates special tokens for offline use so doesn't work with PHP quickstart module.

I am trying to setup request in Postman for this action:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update

But get the following result:
[image]

Is it possible to use HTTP for this API?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to add `?valueInputOption=RAW` on the end of my URL request and removed `valueInputOption` from the request body JSON.

Comment: There is an anomaly in  "revision": "20181031" of the V4 API discovery specification that incorrectly specifies this parameter as being in a 'query' location instead of a 'path' parameter which can explain the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The valueInputOption should be passed as params to the POST URL, it should not be in the request body. 
Also the sheetID and the range should be sent in the URL.
I suppose it should be a POST call not PUT.